# Deleting a single row from more than one tables in more than one databases

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the problem. I have a MySQL database that looks a little like this:

```
Table: db1.group_a
-----------
| name    |
-----------
| Alice   |
| Charlie |
-----------

Table: db2.group_b
----------
| name   |
----------
| Debbie |
| Bob    |
----------
```

*(Yes, each table is in different databases. Also, the actual tables have similar but different structures, I just use one column for simplicity.)*

Each `name` occurs only once in both databases.

Now what I need to do, is find a row (for example, Bob) and delete it from whichever table it's in. I'm thinking of deleting from `group_a` and then checking for affected row(s) and then doing some sort of `if (affected_row < 1) { try_in_next_table(); }` in php.

But it would be ideal to do this entirely in MySQL. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you use the `foreign key` concept for make a relation in between your tables

Comment: @kushalsuthar No, the tables have no relationship. It's just multiple tables doing the same job. It's how it's implemented in my workplace, please don't ask why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few scenarios:

Bulk delete from all databases/tables:

```
DELETE FROM db1.group_a where name='Bob';
DELETE FROM db2.group_b where name='Bob';
```

OR Find actual db/table and then delete (php script):

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$tables = array('db1.group_a','db2.group_b');
foreach ($tables as $t)
  if ($query = $db->query("SELECT * from ".$t." WHERE name=".$db->escape_string("Bob")))
    if ($query->num_rows>0) {
      $db->query("DELETE FROM ".$t." WHERE name=".$db->escape_string("Bob"));
      break; // break foreach
    }
```

OR Delete without selecting:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$tables = array('db1.group_a','db2.group_b');
foreach ($tables as $t)
  if ($query = $db->query("DELETE FROM ".$t." WHERE name=".$db->escape_string("Bob"))
    if ($query->affected_rows>0)
      break; // break foreach
```

Comment: Yeah. I think this covers it.